# How to restrict items with multiple categories?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I've Access 2010 VBA code invoking Outlook to filter e-mail items.

The items must have two categories, e.g. "MOPS, PSA".

The way I use the keyword Restrict is as follows:

```vb
Set rootItems = oFolderRoot.Items
strCategory = sGroupCompanyName & ", MOPS"
'>>>
filterCriteria = "[Categories] = " & QuoteWrap(strCategory)
Set objItems = rootItems.Restrict(filterCriteria)
```

`filterCriteria` equals to [Categories] = 'PSA, MOPS'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying a filter using the `Restrict` method, the filter and property string must match exactly (up to case-sensitivity), for the filter to be applied.

Since mail items may be assigned to multiple categories, you cannot rely on the order in which each category will appear in the comma-delimited string returned when accessing the `Categories` field programmatically.

This is described in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find#remarks):

> **Keywords (or Categories)**
>
> The Categories field is of type keywords, which is designed to hold
>   multiple values. When accessing it programmatically, the Categories
>   field behaves like a Text field, and *the string must match exactly*.
>
> Values in the text string are separated by a comma and a space. This
>   typically means that you cannot use the `Find` and `Restrict` methods on a
>   keywords field if it contains more than one value.

As such, your filter will need to account for both possible cases, using a filter string along the lines of:

```
Set rootItems = oFolderRoot.Items
Set objItems = rootItems.Restrict _
( _
    "[Categories] = '" & sGroupCompanyName & ", MOPS' OR " & _
    "[Categories] = 'MOPS, " & sGroupCompanyName & "'" _
)
```

Comment: A better filter is [Categories] = 'Blue Category' AND [Categories] = 'Green Category'

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Based on the content of the MSDN documentation, I don't understand how that would work for this case - could you please explain?

Comment: Do I have to conclude that    the sample code with OR operator puts stress on the order of values ? @Lee Mac

Comment: Your example depends on the list separator to be ",". OOM parses your restriction and creates a restriction similar  to my example anyway. The order is not important  - you don't need the "or" clause - either one of them will work no matter what the order is - try it.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko

I've tried different methods. No error except that the selected items are only the recent ones (within last two days for my test). I don't undestand why all the others are not catched. 
To be more precise, the other ones are older and I have changed Categories to correspond to PSA and MOPS.

Could that be the reason ? For my application, it's problematic.

Comment: In addition, even if it's not what I expected, the Items.Count is "right" : always the very recent eMail ... Is there any other hidden parameters that filters ?

Comment: filterCriteria = "[Categories] = 'PSA, MOPS' OR [Categories] = 'MOPS, PSA' "

Set objItems = rootItems.Restrict(filterCriteria)
  
objItems is passed to a function to get the eMails properties to Insert them into eMsg Access table.

As yesterday, the objItems.Count gives 1 and when I sent a new eMail today, Count returned 2. As if the other eMails are too old to be filtered. I must tell that they are prior to Oct. 2017